# python : how to replace or remove all traditional chinese string from multi files from multi directory

Tags: replace, cjk

i tried replacing all chinese string to "#"  but it seems not to work

```
import os,re
path = 'F:\\project\\test'
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
        while True:
            content = infile.readline()
            if re.match(r'(.*[\u4E00-\u9FA5]+)|([\u4E00-\u9FA5]+.*)', content.decode('utf-8')):
                print(content.decode('utf-8'))
                content.decode('utf-8').replace(content.decode('utf-8'),"#")
                print(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

i  find some code can get chinese or unchinese txt like (but i have no idea to use)

```
def find_chinese(str):
    pattern = re.compile(r'[^\u4e00-\u9fa5]')
    chinese = re.sub(pattern, '', file)
    print(chinese)

def find_unchinese(str):
    pattern = re.compile(r'[\u4e00-\u9fa5]')
    unchinese = re.sub(pattern, "", file)
    print(unchinese)

str = "2019年1月3日 - python去除空格和换行符的方法 一、去除空格 strip().strip() # ...用replace('\',''),后边的串替换掉前边的posted @ 2016-07-18 08:53 ..."
# get unchinese
find_unchinese(str)
# get chinese
find_chinese(str)
```

i can replace english character like

```
import fileinput,re
filename='F:\\project\\test\\test_script.txt'
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        #pattern = re.compile(r'[^\u4e00-\u9fa5]')
        #chinese = re.sub(pattern, '', str)
        print(line.replace('aaaa', '#'), end='')
        #print(chinese)
```

but if txt file include chinese character like

```
import fileinput,re
filename='F:\\project\\test\\test_script.txt'
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        pattern = re.compile(r'[^\u4e00-\u9fa5]')
        chinese = re.sub(pattern, '', str)
        # print(line.replace('aaaa', '#'), end='')
        print(line.replace(chinese, '#'), end='')
```

console will show UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence
and txt file will be empty

Answer (score 0):

1. python strings are *immutable* so replacing content creates a new string with different content, it's not going to work in-place
2. related to the above once you've read the string from the file it's not really related anymore, you need to write it back at some point if you want the file to be modified (if you don't then carry on)
3. if you assume you're working with utf-8 files only, you can use "encoding='utf-8'" and remove the `b` flag from the mode, Python will do the encoding and decoding on its own
4. `content.replace(content, "#")` means you're replacing *the entire line* with a single `#`, not just CJK data
5. the regex module supports straight search-and-replace, using either a static replacement or a callback function: `re.sub` (where "sub" means "substitute")
6. also not sure why you collect all files in a big list of files and only then perform replacements, why not do your think during the os.walk iteration?
7. note that the range you're specifying is only the BMP CJK range, there have been 6 "astral" extensions since (CJK Unified Ideographs extensions A to F) and a 7th is being planned right now, not to mention the old "compatibility" range which is inside the BMP (U+F900–U+FAFF)
8. also not sure why you're not going to up to U+9FFF which is the actual end of the range, though U+9FF0 and up are currently unassigned

Also note that the unified CJK ranges covers all han-based scripts which includes not just traditional chinese but also simplified, japanese (kanji), korean (hanza) and vietnamese (chữ nôm). And that there are additional non-unified ranges in unicode e.g. U+5169 is *specifically* a traditional chinese character.